# calculate car parking hours in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one doubt in sql server. How to calculate car login and logout time details?

table: cardetails

Here need to calculate each car how many hours spend in parking area.

```
creatE TABLE [dbo].[CarDetails](
    [carid] [int] NULL,
    [DateTimeDetail] [datetime] NULL,
    [Flag] [varchar](50) NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2019-01-20T19:05:00.000' AS DateTime), N'in')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2019-01-20T22:30:00.000' AS DateTime), N'out')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2019-01-20T20:30:10.000' AS DateTime), N'in')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2019-01-21T02:10:10.000' AS DateTime), N'out')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2019-01-23T07:07:40.000' AS DateTime), N'in')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2019-01-23T10:50:40.000' AS DateTime), N'out')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2019-01-23T11:00:10.000' AS DateTime), N'in')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2019-01-23T14:15:30.000' AS DateTime), N'out')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2019-01-21T08:20:10.000' AS DateTime), N'in')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CarDetails] ([carid], [DateTimeDetail], [Flag]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2019-01-21T10:20:10.000' AS DateTime), N'out')
GO
```

These are the records:

```
carid   DateTimeDetail              Flag
1       2019-01-20 19:05:00.000     in
1       2019-01-20 22:30:00.000     out
2       2019-01-20 20:30:10.000     in
2       2019-01-21 02:10:10.000     out
3       2019-01-23 07:07:40.000     in
3       2019-01-23 10:50:40.000     out
3       2019-01-23 11:00:10.000     in
3       2019-01-23 14:15:30.000     out
2       2019-01-21 08:20:10.000     in
2       2019-01-21 10:20:10.000     out
```

Based on above data I want output like below :

```
carid | DateTimeDetails | Totaltime(hh:mm:ss)
  1     |2019-01-20       | 03:25:00
  2     |2019-01-20       | 05 :49:40
  2     |2019-01-21       | 02:00:00
  3     |2019-01-23       | 06:58:20
```

I tried like below

```
select a.carid ,  sum(datediff(mm,b.datetimedetail,a.datetimedetail))as totalmm from  CarDetails a join  CarDetails b
on a.carid=b.carid

where a.datetimedetail<=(select max(c.[DateTimeDetail]) from CarDetails c join CarDetails a on a.carid=c.carid
)
group by a.carid
```

please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: Could you have values over 24 hours?

Comment: In/Out should be in different columns...that would make it really simple...is this viable for you?

Comment: For things like in/out stuff the format the OP has is very common @Fleshy. They're effectively logs of actions, and logs don't go back and update previous logs when there's a further action. I would actually suggest it a bad idea to change the design of their table here, and instead they should be normalising their data in their queries, or using a view. Call systems (that I've used) use a similar design as well, where there's one row for the call starting and one for it finishing.

Comment: FYI, @gbalu , when asking questions, it's seen as courtesy to makes answers that solve your problem as the solution. You've asked 33 questions and *never* marked any as a solution. This can affect the answers you get in the future, as people won't put the time in if you aren't going to respond to their attempts. I would suggest reviewing the questions you have asked and marking solutions where needed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite give you the expected results in your post, however, I have good reason for it not to be, and I suspect your expected results are wrong:

```
--Because, from experience, people can somehow enter things twice before exiting...
WITH Grp AS(
    SELECT CD.carid,
           CD.DateTimeDetail,
           CD.Flag,
           COUNT(CASE Flag WHEN 'Out' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY carid ORDER BY CD.DateTimeDetail ASC
                                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.CarDetails CD),
InOut AS(
    SELECT carid,
           MIN(CASE Flag WHEN 'In' THEN Grp.DateTimeDetail END) AS TimeIn,
           MAX(CASE Flag WHEN 'Out' THEN Grp.DateTimeDetail END) AS [TimeOut]
    FROM Grp
    GROUP BY carid, grp)
SELECT carid,
       CONVERT(date,TimeIn) AS DateTimeDetails,
       CONVERT(time(0),DATEADD(SECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,TimeIn, [TimeOut])),'00:00:00')) AS TotalTime
FROM InOut
GROUP BY carid,
         CONVERT(date,TimeIn)
ORDER BY carid ASC;
```

This gives the results below:

```
carid       DateTimeDetails TotalTime
----------- --------------- ----------------
1           2019-01-20      03:25:00
2           2019-01-20      05:40:00
2           2019-01-21      02:00:00
3           2019-01-23      06:58:20
```

Notice I have a `05:40:00` for car 2 on 2019-01-20. Car 2 enters at 20:30:10 and leaves at 02:10:10, which is 5 hours, and 40 minutes later; not 05 hours 49 minutes and 40 seconds later. if you have that time in your expected results for a reason, you need to explain why.

***Note:*** This will not work if a car stays more than 24 hours! You didn't respond to my question, so I have assumed not. If they can, SQL Server does not support times great than 24 hours, therefore you will be better returning the number of seconds, and having your application display a 24+ hour time.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select carid,dateIn, cast(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', timeout)), '00:00:00.000') as time) timeOut 
from (
    select carid,cast([DateTimeDetail]as DATE) DateIn , 
        (select top 1 [DateTimeDetail] 
            from [CarDetails] b 
            where b.carid=a.carid and b.[DateTimeDetail]>a.[DateTimeDetail] and flag='out' )
        -[DateTimeDetail] timeOut
from [CarDetails] a
where Flag='in') c
group by  carid,dateIn
```

This gives the results below:

```
carid   dateIn  timeOut
1   2019-01-20  03:25:00.0000000
2   2019-01-20  05:40:00.0000000
2   2019-01-21  02:00:00.0000000
3   2019-01-23  06:58:20.0000000
```